# How to append a character from a filename to the end of each line of a file from a terminal?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I know how to do this using Python, but I'd like to learn how to do it with awk or sed or whatever the best command line method. I have file names that look like

```
A1.txt
A2.txt
...
B99.txt
B100.txt
```

Each file contains one line. I'd like to append the letter in the file name to the end of the line. Then the contents of the files would look like:

```
a one file contents A
a two file contents A
...
b ninety nine file contents B
b one hundred file contents B
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the files in place, sed's `-i` option is handy:

```
for f in *.txt; do ltr=${f:0:1}; sed -i "s/$/ $ltr/" "$f" ; done
```

Explanation:

- `for f in *.txt`

  This starts a loop over all `.txt` files in the current directory.
- `ltr=${f:0:1}`

  This extracts the first character from the file name
- `sed -i "s/$/ $ltr/" "$f"`

  This replaces the end of each line in the file named by `f` with a space and the first character of the file name.  In more detail:

  - `-i` tells `sed` to make the changes in place.
  - `s/$/ $ltr/` is the substitute command.  The format is `s/old/new/` where, here, old is `$` which matches at the end of the line, and new is `$ltr` which is a space and the first character of the file's name.
  - `"$f"` tells `sed` top operate of the file named by `f`.

Answer (score 2):

How about pure bash?

```
for file in *.txt; do
    IFS= read -r line < "$file"
    printf '%s %s\n' "$line" "${file::1}" > "$file"
done
```